# Case front fan blocks HDD bays

Tags: computer-building, fan, case

I'm building a new computer with a friend at the moment, but we've installed the front fan and discovered that it blocks access to all of the 3.5" bays. Any devices we put there stick way out for the screw holes to line up (we had to mount the SSD backwards for its holes to line up).

The fan is on the inside of the case with the screws on the outside going in (that's the only way the case works for it to be installed).

Did we do something wrong? Does this case just have a really crappy design? [This is the case in question.](http://www.raidmax.com/chassis/super_viper.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The harddrives should be no where near the front fan (an inch or two of clearance). The drives should be mounted with the connectors facing the interior of the case, and protruding an inch or so out the back of the harddrive cage.

You should be using the back and middle holes for mounting drives, not the middle and front holes. You can see where the tool-less mounting brackets should be in this image:

[image: RaidMax SuperViper Case Without Side panel]

Here is an image of how much the drives should stick out into the interior of the case:

[image: RaidMax SuperViper Harddrive Installation Closeup]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, I appreciate it!